# Mock generic, dynamic interface with Moq

Tags: .net, dynamic, moq

I have the following interface to mock out:

```
internal interface IRenderer
{
    void Render<T>(StringWriter stringWriter, T item) where T : struct;

    void Render(StringWriter stringWriter, decimal item);

    void Render(StringWriter stringWriter, string item);
}
```

And a test as follows:

```
[Test]
[TestCase("dummy-string", "dummy-string")]
[TestCase(123, "123")]
[TestCase(123.456, "123.456")]
[TestCase(true, "True")]
[TestCase('C', "C")]
public void RendersExpectedValues(dynamic item, string rendered)
{
    // Do some stuff
    using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter(renderedBuilder)
    {
        _mockRenderer.Setup(x => x.Render(textWriter, item));
        _renderer.Render(textWriter, item);
    }

   Assert.It.Worked();
}
```

As you can see, `item` is `dynamic`, the overload is determined at runtime... I've played around with

```
Type type = item.GetType();
_mockRenderer.Setup(x => x.Render<type>(textWriter, item));
```

and

```
Type type = item.GetType();
_mockRenderer.Setup(x => x.Render<typeof(type)>(textWriter, item));
```

Neither of which work (of course).

Is this possible?  I can remove the string test case to a separate test.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a direct away around this - invariably, I get:

> Error: An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation`

when trying to use a `dynamic` in the Setup. AFAIK you'll need to do explicit `Setup()`s on each of the supported types.

However, you can DRY this up a bit, however with a generic setup helper method, e.g.:

```
   static class Helpers
   {
      public static Mock<IRenderer> Setup<T>(this Mock<IRenderer> mockRenderer) where T : struct
      {
         mockRenderer.Setup(x => x.Render(It.IsAny<StringWriter>(), It.IsAny<T>()))
            .Callback<StringWriter, T>((sw, s) => sw.Write(s));
         return mockRenderer;
      }
   }
```

Which can then be setup + invoked:

```
  [Test]
  [TestCase("dummy-string",  "dummy-string")]
  [TestCase(123, "123")]
  [TestCase(123.456, "123.456")]
  [TestCase(true, "True")]
  public void RendersExpectedValuesString(dynamic item, string rendered)
  {
     var _mockRenderer = new Mock<IRenderer>()
        .Setup<double>()
        .Setup<bool>()
        .Setup<int>()
        .Setup<decimal>();
     _mockRenderer.Setup(x => x.Render(It.IsAny<StringWriter>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Callback<StringWriter, string>((sw, s) => sw.Write(s));

     var renderedBuilder = new StringBuilder();
     var sut = new SomethingWhichUsesRenderer(_mockRenderer.Object);

      // Do some stuff
      using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter(renderedBuilder))
      {
        sut.DoSomething(stringWriter, item);

        // This obviously just tests the Mock ...
        Assert.AreEqual(renderedBuilder.ToString(), rendered);

        // Do actual unit tests + Mock.Verifies here
      }
  }
```